# How do I print the list of registry keys in HKCU\Environment to SDTOUT using JScript (WSH)?

Tags: scripting, registry, environment-variables, javascript, wsh

I want to iterate over the environment keys and print a list of these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the user environment variables via the appropriate [`WshEnvironment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7w15a0.aspx) collection; there's no need to mess with the registry:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oUserEnv = oShell.Environment("User");

var colVars = new Enumerator(oUserEnv);
for(; ! colVars.atEnd(); colVars.moveNext())
{
  WScript.Echo(colVars.item());
}
```

This script will output the variable names along with values (non-expanded), e.g.:

```
TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp
TMP=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp
Path=%PATH%
PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.tcl
```

If you need the variable names only, you can extract them like this:

```
// ...
var strVarName;
for(; ! colVars.atEnd(); colVars.moveNext())
{
  strVarName = colVars.item().split("=")[0];
  WScript.Echo(strVarName);
}
```

**Edit:** To expand the variables, use the [`WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf.aspx) method; for example:

```
// ...
var arr, strVarName, strVarValue;
for(; ! colVars.atEnd(); colVars.moveNext())
{
  arr = colVars.item().split("=");
  strVarName = arr[0];
  strVarValue = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(arr[1]);

  WScript.Echo(strVarName + "=" + strVarValue);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. how about if i want to expand the variables?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried the code given in the answer, I got an error on line 4.  I believe it *should* be:

```
var colVars = new Enumerator(oUserEnv);
```