# How to enumerate my environmental variables in JScript?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, wsh, jscript

How do I enumerate my process's environmental variables in JScript, and, say, output them to the screen?

Comment: how about `for (var o in colSystemEnvVars) alert(o+":"+colSystemEnvVars[o])`

Comment: @Helen: That's not specific to my process.

Comment: By "process" do you mean an arbitrary running process, or the script host (cscript/wscript) process?

Comment: @Helen: The current cscript/wscript process -- the same data `WshShell.Environment("Process")` provides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is the same as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911488/how-do-i-print-the-list-of-registry-keys-in-hkcu-environment-to-sdtout-using-jscr/1916818#1916818), only you use `WshShell.Environment("Process")` instead of `WshShell.Environment("User")`:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oUserEnv = oShell.Environment("Process");

var colVars = new Enumerator(oUserEnv);
for(; ! colVars.atEnd(); colVars.moveNext())
{
  WScript.Echo(colVars.item());
}
```

Comment: Oooh so the trick is to use `Enumerator`? I didn't know that, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yes, that's how you enumerate collections, e.g. [FileSystemObject collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x75sb7ff.aspx) or WMI query results. `for ... in` is for arrays and object properties only.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wsh%20environment%20variables) gives the following example:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colSystemEnvVars = objShell.Environment("System")
Set colUserEnvVars = objShell.Environment("User")
Wscript.Echo "Computer-specific PATH Environment Variable"
Wscript.Echo colSystemEnvVars("PATH")
Wscript.Echo "User-specific PATH Environment Variable"
Wscript.Echo colUserEnvVars("PATH")
```

Comment: Right, that gets me the *value* of any variable whose name I already know. But my question was, how do I **enumerate** all the variables in the first place?

Comment: @mplungjan: That's true, but I don't really mind that part; they're really similar.